# Android add line markers to edges of arc

Tags: java, android, math, android-canvas, wear-os

How can we add `line` markers at the edge of an `arc`.

We know that an `arc` can be drawn using the following:

```
canvas.drawArc(arcBounds, 0, 90, false, paint);
```

The above statement will draw an `arc` from 3pm to 6pm. I would like to add `line` markers at both edges of the `arc` as seen in the image below for example.

[image]

I am able to draw circles at both the edges using the following:

```
canvas.drawCircle(endX, endY, 5, timeArcPaints);
```

I have the `startX` and `startY`, `endX` and `endY` positions for the `arc`, however I am not sure how can i draw the `line` marker such that it is at the same angle as the `arc` endpoints.

```
public void drawLine (float startX, 
                float startY, 
                float stopX, 
                float stopY, 
                Paint paint)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code for custom view

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.view.View;

public class MarkerView extends View {

    private final Paint markerPaint;
    private RectF oval;
    private final int boundingRectDimens = 200;
    private int centerX;
    private int centerY;

    private final float startAngle = 190;
    private final float sweepAngle = 90;
    private final float markerAngle = 180; // angle of markers w.r.t start point and end/sweep point


    public MarkerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        markerPaint = createMarkerPaint();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        centerX = w / 2;
        centerY = h / 2;
        oval = new RectF(centerX - boundingRectDimens,
                centerY - boundingRectDimens,
                centerX + boundingRectDimens,
                centerY + boundingRectDimens);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        canvas.drawArc(oval, startAngle, sweepAngle, false, markerPaint);


        float startX, startY, endX, endY;
        // calculate start points.

        //get a line from startAngle till markerAngle.
        startX = (float) (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(startAngle)) * boundingRectDimens + centerX);
        startY = (float) (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(startAngle)) * boundingRectDimens + centerY);
        endX = (float) (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(startAngle + markerAngle)) * boundingRectDimens + centerX);
        endY = (float) (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(startAngle + markerAngle)) * boundingRectDimens + centerY);

        // we need to draw only a part of the entire line, using vector for this.
        // vector dimens.
        float desiredLen = 0.05f;  // maker height can be adjusted by changing this value.
        float upLen = 1 - desiredLen;
        float downLen = 1 + desiredLen;
        // calculate down vector.
        float desiredX = downLen * (startX - endX) + endX;
        float desiredY = downLen * (startY - endY) + endY;

        markerPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, desiredX, desiredY, markerPaint);
        // get up vector
        desiredX = upLen * (startX - endX) + endX;
        desiredY = upLen * (startY - endY) + endY;
        canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, desiredX, desiredY, markerPaint);


        // repeat same for end/sweep point.
        startX = (float) (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(startAngle + sweepAngle)) * boundingRectDimens + centerX);
        startY = (float) (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(startAngle + sweepAngle)) * boundingRectDimens + centerY);
        endX = (float) (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(startAngle + sweepAngle + markerAngle)) * boundingRectDimens + centerX);
        endY = (float) (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(startAngle + sweepAngle + markerAngle)) * boundingRectDimens + centerY);

        // calculate down vector.
        desiredX = downLen * (startX - endX) + endX;
        desiredY = downLen * (startY - endY) + endY;

        markerPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, desiredX, desiredY, markerPaint);
        // get up vector
        desiredX = upLen * (startX - endX) + endX;
        desiredY = upLen * (startY - endY) + endY;
        canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, desiredX, desiredY, markerPaint);


    }


    private Paint createMarkerPaint() {
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
        p.setDither(true);
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        p.setStrokeWidth(20);
        p.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND); // makes the stroke projects out as semicircle
        p.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND); // makes outer edges of a join meet in circular arc
        return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the markerAngle? The arc can be drawn at any angle based on the user input, so how do I make sure that the markerAngle works?

Comment: Markerangle is angle between marker and arc point at which marker is to be drawn. It looks good in the range of 165 to 195, u can play with different values and decide yourself the best value for it.

Comment: If you want marker simply straight, keep markerAngle at 180

Comment: Hmm I must be doing something wrong here. The two markers are the showing up at the center of the circle rather than the end of the arcs. I presume that this is because of the boundingDimens that has been hardcoded.

Comment: I will upvote the answer, since it is a step in the right direction. If you could help out figure out the boundingDimens that would be great in the meantime.

Comment: boundingDimens is a simple rect in which we draw our arc, if we use sweepAngle of 360 then circle would be drawn(arc will go full circle).I suspect you have messed up some point with other point. Ok I suggest you to try to visualise by closing the arc one time and if that doesn’t helps, kindly share ur code. My answer is working. I have checked it multiple times with varying angles spread across all the quadrants.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198495/discussion-between-user2511882-and-rishabh-dhawan).

Comment: How to chat? I am new here, this is my second answer

Comment: You may simply click on the link. It directs you to a separate page within stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

In android paint holds the style and color info of how to draw your view.You need to use paint Style to achieve your desired drawing.

create a paint for marker

```
 private Paint createMarkerPaint(){
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setDither(true);
    p.setColor(Color.RED);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    p.setStrokeWidth(20);
    p.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND); // makes the stroke projects out as semicircle
    p.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND); // makes outer edges of a join meet in circular arc
    return p;
}
```

use this function to create line markers

```
 private void drawLineMarkers(Canvas c, float startX, float startY, float endX, float endY){

    int lineHeight = 20; // play with it
    int lineWidth = 20; // play with it
    c.drawLine(startX, startY, startX - lineWidth, startY - lineHeight, markerPaint);
    c.drawLine(startX, startY, startX + lineWidth, startY + lineHeight, markerPaint);

    c.drawLine(endX, endY, endX - lineWidth, endY - lineHeight, markerPaint);
    c.drawLine(endX, endY, endX + lineWidth, endY + lineHeight, markerPaint);

}
```

Comment: I am sorry. My question was how to find the draw the line in the appropriate plane.

Comment: Do you want to know how to calculate the points(startX, startY, endX, endY) used in drawLineMarkers().

Comment: Yes. And also how do we draw the line in that plane.

Comment: I have implemented the solution, but due to experiments it is not clean, I will clean it, add supporting documentation and post the answer tomorrow.